# New Date Returns "Invalid Date" When I Pass In a Variable Parameter

Tags: javascript

I would like a new date like this

```
var d = new Date();
var currentYear = d.getFullYear();
var christmasDate = new Date(Date.UTC(currentYear, 11, 25));
else if (tds[l].textContent === "26" && new Date() == christmasDate) {
    var boxing_day = document.getElementById("boxing-day");
    boxing_day.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    var txt3 = "\r\nBoxing Day";
    tds[l].textContent += txt3;
    tds[l].classList.add("boxing-day-style");
    tds[l].setAttribute("style", "white-space: pre; background: red; font-size: 20px; padding: 0; margin: 0; width: 15%; height: 15vh;");
}
```

but it returns Invalid Date. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Could you post a full code snippet? That one has an 'else if' statement but no opening 'if...'.

Comment: What is the value of `currentYear` that you get?

Comment: `currentYear` returns 2018 but it changes when i click a button

Answer (score 0):

Simple mistake?

```
(new Date()).getFullYear()
// returns the current year
```

So your code should probably be:

```
                 var d = new Date();
                 var currentYear = d.getUTCFullYear();
```